# How do I find an .apk file that's not even installed?

Tags: apk, file-management, google-files

There is an `.apk` file when I use Google Files. But it says it's not installed. It is taking up over one MB of memory.

How do I remove it? Better yet how do I find it?

Comment: In which path is the APK file located? Shouldn't you be able to delete the APK file directly in Google files app?

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called Total Commander that's very good for exploring root-level assets.  It may take some poking around, once installed, but it's been useful for me.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander

Comment: Note that "exploring root-level assets" only works if the device is rooted. Otherwise, it only sees the same files and folders as other file manager apps.